# Any restrictions on the use of ArcGIS REST API?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

I'm building a PHP script which ends up with an array of latitude, longitude pairs (around 2,500), and I want to be able to reverse geocode them into full adresses, then recording them on my database.

I ran a search on Reverse Geocoding and have narrowed my options to Google and ESRI. I'm leaning towards ESRI because they have a REST API, whereas Google works via Javascript, which would give me much more trouble to implement.

But before I start coding I was curious whether the ArcGIS REST API has any restrictions at all: is it free or do I need to subscribe? Do I need an API key? If so, where do I get it? Are there restrictions regarding requests per minute / hour / month? I've looked around their docs, but can't seem to find anything non-technical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ArcGIS services *will* cost money in production. According to [the World Geocoding Service's documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Batch_geocode_authentication/02r3000000n3000000/), you will need [an ArcGIS Online Subscription](http://www.arcgis.com/features/plans/pricing.html) to use them. Limitations are rated on the number of requests made, not on any throughput. [It will cost 40 credits per 1000 geocodes](http://www.arcgis.com/features/plans/credits.html).

Comment: Well, in my defense I did go through that article and was still puzzled. I seemed to have been under the impression that there was a difference between "multiple single requests" and "a single batch request". Silly me :)

Answer (score 1):

Google has a rest api as well. It may also cost you. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Ah, thanks for that! Don't know how I missed it :) Also, 2,500 free requests per 24 hour period seems very reasonable to me and it certainly fits the immediate needs of my script.